# How can I get private information from a class pointed to by a private pointer inside another class?

Tags: c++, pointers, derived-class

I have a class, `Player`, with member variable `Creature *character` which will point to `Elf : public Creature` derived class.

I want to be able to declare a `Player` object and then have one of its members point to a `Elf` and get information.

I understand that data members should be private, but is this a special case or how can I get information from the `Elf` members from my `main` function?

```
void Player::set_character(Creature &c)
{
  character = &c;
}

...
Player me;
Elf me_elf;
me.set_character(me_elf);
```

Comment: That looks OK. Can you post a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: The code you have posted looks correct, I suspect there's some other part of it that is failing. What exactly is the runtime error, and can you please produce a http://sscce.org/

Comment: I may have got it working now somehow, I wish I knew what I had just done. Sorry about that, now I just need to know how to access the `Elf` when the pointer is private, assuming I want to keep it private.

Comment: Ok, so you shouldn't really "recycle the question" by changing the title and asking a different question. The simple answer to your question is either "don't make it private", "Use accessor functions (setters/getters)" or "make it a friend".

Comment: @MatsPetersson Sorry if that bothered you, I am a strong believer in recycling :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via public methods of `Player`:

```
class Creature
{
 public:
  virtual void hello() const = 0;
};

class Player{
 public:
  void hello() const { charatcer->hello(); }
  // other methods as before
 private:
  Creature* character;
};
```

Comment: So this code works, but only when I erase the `= 0;` part. Otherwise, It gives the error "cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Creature'" because the virtual functions are pure within 'Creature': and then it goes to the function with the `= 0;` at the end. This occurs on my constructor inside the derived classes such as `Elf : public Creature`. Why do you use the `= 0;` here?

Comment: @Leonardo that makes `void hello()` a pure virtual method in `Creature`. I was assuming `Creature` was a base class and everything would be implemented in the derived types. If you want to instantiate `Creature`, remove the `=0` and add an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a "has a" relationship, you'll have to use wrapper functions to access the data.

if you have a "is a" relationship, you'll be able to access the data if the data is "protected". Without any other troubles. Having protected allows the derived class to access the data.

Comment: True I am sure protected would work but that defeats the purpose of private.

Comment: The WHOLE point of `protected` is that it allows classes that are releated, but not classes that are unrelated to access the members. It's all depending on exactly what you want to achieve. The distinctions between `public`, `protected` and `private` are there for the very reason that different types of designs require different levels of access. [This is why we need a more complete example and a properly formulated question - recycling is good when it comes to things that are truly material - the bits and bytes in computers are recycled anyway]

Comment: @juanchopanza okay, because it does not have a "is a" relationship right?

Comment: @Leonardo Exactly. Plus you somehow need to get the information to `main` anyway, so you would still have to pass it on from the `Player` interface.

Comment: @Leonardo you can create function in the player interface, and with dynamic binding, you could at runtime be able to call the right display function for the creature.